# Does Ubuntu enabled 'ANSI-C compiler' and 'build system' by default?

Tags: php, linux, apache-http-server, ubuntu, installation

I'm going to install PHP and Apache, and instructions say: "You need a respectable ANSI-C compiler and build system,two items that are available through all of the major distributions' package managers", so I checked out Ubuntu's synaptic package manager, but I'm not sure whether these two are enabled by default.

Answer (score 4):

If you know this little about the build process, I wouldn't go compiling Apache and PHP.

Instead, install Ubuntu's precompiled packages like this:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 php5
```

If you still want to go ahead with compilation, the other answers are what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu the meta package that will install the tools you need is called `build-essential`.  It will install `gcc`, `make`, and some header files.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this should be as simple as sudo apt-get install gcc to install the GNU C compiler which should work for your purposes.

You may also need build-essential.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you will need `gcc` and `make` :)